# Make phpStorm upload generated files together with original ones

Tags: phpstorm

I have some build and compile tasks that generate new files, e.g.

[image]

Now I need to upload those files to my server. I always upload the original file and forget about the compiled ones, as they aren't visible originally, but hidden behind the es6 file in this case.

[image]

Is there any way to make phpStorm auto upload the compiled files whenever I upload the original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is '`Upload external changes`' option in `Settings/Build, Execution, Deployment/Deployment/Options` that allows updating files generated by external processes.

Comment: Thank you! Will this upload the files only on upload of the original file, or every time the file is changed?

Comment: Every time the file is changed ;)