# PhpStorm: minify correctly but does not upload the minified file

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I use the YUI Compressor and file watcher to minify files.

Works great: it creates a minified version of the file:

[image]

However, only the original file is uploaded automatically and I need to manually upload the `.min.css` file.

Any idea ?

[image]

Comment: Show you File Watcher -- solution must be there (correct data in `Output paths to refresh` field).

Comment: screenshot added

Comment: Looks OK at first glance (at very least it has stuff in that field and it seem valid). I suggest to check https://stackoverflow.com/a/34017788/783119

Comment: Tools > Deployment > Options > Automatic upload > "Upload external changes" checkbox